# Django - How can I change profile view in admin's panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Well, I created a model Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)
```

And added it to admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Profile
```

So, I have user's panel on my admin's panel. But every profile in the list of profiles are called 'profile object(1)', 'profile object(2)' and etc, but when I tap on the link, I can see the user's name. So, how can I can change the view of profiles in the list of profiles so they are called there as user is called?

How it looks like in admin's panel
[image: How it looks like in admin's panel]

How it looks like inside the profile
[image: How it looks like inside the profile]

And how I want it to look like (modified with F12):
[image]

EDITED: How my **str** looks like (commented, because doesn't work):

```
# __str__ - более удобное отображение в админке
#    def __str__(self):
#         return self.user_username
```

Comment: Have you defined `__str__` on your Profile model?

Comment: @thebjorn - well, I've tried to do that, but got a mistake. I've added how it looks like, but doesn't work

Comment: Thank's now ir works:D @thebjorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `__str__()`

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution in your #admin.py you can write `list_display = ["user__username",]`

Comment: This kind of field declaration often throws an error.

Comment: In my opinion if you want to display only one field like a user username this solution is better then  `str method`. but if you want to display id and username together like this `(id) username` that is a good way do use `str method`

Comment: Legit, but my principle is to always override the \_\_str\_\_ method.